# Problema al deshabilitar botón en Firefox mediante Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He metido dentro de un if statement que se deshabilite un botón de compra si ciertas condiciones previas no se cumplen. Os linkeo sólo la parte del código pertinente dentro de la función. Primero he probado con `.disabled`:

```
if (finalprice1_1 <= 0 || userstring1.length < 3 || userstring1.length > 16 || passwordstring1.length < 3 || passwordstring1.length > 16)  {
    orderbutton1.disabled = true;
} else {
    orderbutton1.disabled = false;
}
```

Me funciona perfectamente en Chrome pero no en Firefox. Tengo la versión más reciente de ambos navegadores instalada.

Luego he probado con `.setAttribute`:

```
if (finalprice1_1 <= 0 || userstring1.length < 3 || userstring1.length > 16 || passwordstring1.length < 3 || passwordstring1.length > 16) {
    orderbutton1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Idem. En Chrome funciona nuevamente a la perfección, en Firefox no.

¿Tenéis alguna idea de qué puedo hacer que Firefox también me haga caso? :)

Gracias de antemano!

Edit:

Lo tengo dentro de una función grande llamada `function paybutton1() {...}`.
Dentro de la función llamo al botón de forma habitual:

```
var orderbutton1 = document.getElementById("orderbutton1");
```

Al botón le tengo asignada la función como atributo `onclick="paybutton1()"`

Edit 2:

Esto me funciona en Chrome pero no en Firefox:

```js
function ejemplo() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  
  if (input1.length < 1) {
    button1.disabled = true;
  } else {
    button1.disabled = false;
  }
 }
 
 function reset() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  button1.disabled = false;
 }
```

```html
Si estoy vacío, el botón se deshabilita (en teoría) : <br>
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeydown="reset()">
<br><br>
<button id="button1" onclick="ejemplo()">Prueba</button>
```

Aquí de la otra manera lo mismo también:

```js
function ejemplo() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  
  if (input1.length < 1) {
    button1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
  }
 }
 
 function reset() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  button1.removeAttribute("disabled");
 }
```

```html
Si estoy vacío, el botón se deshabilita (en teoría) : <br>
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeydown="reset()">
<br><br>
<button id="button1" onclick="ejemplo()">Prueba</button>
```

Comment: Me ha pasado alguna vez que en Firefox está disabled pero no lo parece (no está gris). Has comprobado haciendo click que de verdad es disabled?. Mira [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10765328/3045491)

Comment: No hay razón lógica para que Firefox no ejecute tu código correctamente, teniendo en cuenta que `disabled` es una propiedad compatible con todo navegador. ¿Algún mensaje en la consola?

Comment: ¿será la configuración de Firefox?

Comment: @lois6b Lo he comprobado y me deja ir a Paypal con la variable del precio igual a cero y con campos sin rellenar. No bueno. Gustavo García, no hay mensajes en la consola de Firefox al inspeccionar, simplemente no me bloquea correctamente el botón. Ixi, ni idea, pero le he preguntado a 2 colegas que lo prueben en su Firefox y más de lo mismo (¿¿sólo podría ser que los 3 tengamos la configuración mal??). Me resulta super desesperante porque no encuentro el fallo por ningún lado y en Chrome si me funciona con ambos métodos en el código.

Comment: ¿Llamas ese código desde una función? Si es así, ¿cómo se llama la función?

Comment: @A.Cedano Te lo edité arriba en el post! :) Pero lo dicho, en Chrome funciona todo perfectamente. Sólo tengo el problema con Firefox.

Comment: ¿Podrías proveer un ejemplo pequeño pero que reproduzca el problema?

Comment: Pero está activo en realidad o está inactivo pero no se pone gris. He leído que en algunos casos aunque está activo no se pone gris en FF y que hay que hacerlo por CSS. ¿Confirmas que el botón sigue activo, es decir, se puede hacer click en él? _disabled elements are rendered depends on the user agent. For example, some user agents "gray out" disabled menu items, button labels, etc_

Comment: Llevan 6 años discutiendo sobre esto en Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072 y parece que no se ponen de acuerdo. ¿No puedes hacerlo usando jQuery?

Comment: @Gustavo García Te hice un edit arriba con dos snippets siguiendo el mismo modelo de código que tengo. En mi Chrome van, en mi Firefox no. A.Cedano, preferiría conseguir hacerlo sin jquery a no ser que no me quede otra. El botón está activo, me lleva a Paypal sin cumplirse las condiciones del if/else - esto como dicho sólo en Firefox, en Chrome se bloquea bien si los valores introducidos en los inputs no siguen mis reglas.

Comment: Pasó la prueba en Firefox 23 hasta 52.0.1 bajo Ubuntu 16.04 y Windows 7.  **No pude reproducir tu problema**. Es posible que se deba a alguna extensión.

Comment: En alguna parte recomendaban poner al input: `<input .... autocomplete="off">`
 en otra parte decían que podría ser un problema ocasionado por firebug que a veces se resolvía reiniciando Firefox. Y en el enlace que te puse más arriba insistían en que era un bug, pero esas discusiones datan de 6 años ¡cuidado si instalaste un Firefox de  hace 6 años! :) Prueba lo de autocomplete y comenta.

Comment: @psy El código funciona correctamente, debe de ser configuración local. Asegurate de tener Javascript Habilitado y extensiones como [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/noscript/) deshabilitada/apagada

Answer (score -1):

Y detectando Firefox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function siesfirefox() {
var a=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1;a&&/*screen.width<770&&*/(
document.getElementById("tu-boton").style.display="none")
}
siesfirefox();
</script>
```

Fijate en ésto:

**screen.width<770&&**
Inclusive le estas diciendo que si la pantalla es menor que 770 px (o el valor que quieras), tu botón no se mostrará en móviles.
Puede ser el botón por su ID, o un div, etc. Lo que tú quieras...

Answer (score -1):

Te sugiero usar [**jQuery**](https://www.jquery.com), así no tendrás que preocuparte de cosas triviales como "**que explorador usas**" y ademas escribirás menos, aquí te dejo una rutina hecha con **jQuery** que funciona en cualquier explorador:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("input").on("keyup",function () {
  $("button").prop("disabled",this.value==="");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input><button disabled>Enviar</button>
```